# invalid type code:AC

Tags: java, файлы

Пробую сериализовать обьект.
Идея такая: Есть класс HA(что-то типа человека) у него есть поля 
1)Имя
2)Что делает
3)Id
4)Дата
и есть методы 
1)write
2)read
Когда я пытаюсь считать второй обьект из файла то
собственно в методе read вылетает исключение "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC"

Вот класс HA:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class HA implements Serializable {


    private String name; //Имя
    private String work; //Дело
    private String date; //Дата
    private int id; //номер записи 

    private String getDate() { //Получение даты в формате дд.мм.гг
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat();
        return dateFormat.format(currentDate).toString();
    }



    public HA (String name,String work,int id) { //Конструктор 
        this.name = name;
        this.work = work;
        this.date = getDate(); 
        this.id = id; 
    }

    public void display(HA ha) {
        out.println("---------------------");
        out.println("id:"+ha.id);
        out.println("Кто:"+ha.name);
        out.println("Что:"+ha.work);
        out.println("Когда:"+ha.date);
        out.println("---------------------");
    }




}
```

А вот и методы с main:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Ser1 {
   static String PATH="IO4.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        write("Рик","Убрал мусор",13);
        read();
    }

    static void write(String name,String work,int id) throws Exception {
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH,true);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
            HA ha = new HA(name,work,id);
            oos.writeObject(ha);
            oos.flush();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

    static void read() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<HA> List = new ArrayList<>();

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {



            while(true) {
                try{
                    List.add((HA) ois.readObject());
                }catch (EOFException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (HA ha:List) {
            ha.display(ha);
        }
    }

}
```

Пробовал разные варианты,читал похожие,но не смог найти ответа.
Помогите найти ошибку.
Спасибо.

Comment: если вы подключили интерфейс, то почему вы не переопределили методы?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    public class HA implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String DATE_FORMATTER_PATERN = "dd.MM.yyyy";

        private final String name; //Имя
        private final String work; //Дело
        private final LocalDate date; //Дата
        private final int id; //номер записи 

        public HA(int id, String name, String work) { //Конструктор 
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.work = work;
            this.date = LocalDate.now();
        }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append("\r\n---------------------")
            .append("\r\nid:").append(id)
            .append("\r\nКто:").append(name)
            .append("\r\nЧто:").append(work)
            .append("r\nКогда:").append(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMATTER_PATERN)))
            .append("\r\n---------------------")
            .toString();
}

    }

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class Ser1 {

    static String PATH = "IO4.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<HA> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new HA(13, "Рик", "Убрал мусор"));
        write(list);
        System.out.println(read());
    }

    static void write(final List<HA> list) throws Exception {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(PATH)))) {
            oos.writeObject(list);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static List<HA> read() throws Exception {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(PATH)))) {
            return (List<HA>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```